# Unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403) using csrf with Spring Security v3.0.0 and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-3

I try to configure security of my application but I get "Unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403)" and I don't know what is the problem. I register a user then login, do some stuff on a "/design" page, press submit and get the Error. As I know (from Spring in Action book) Thymeleaf automatically include hidden field with CSRF token for each html page.

When I disable csrf in SecurityFilterChain my web application works fine. My SecurityConfig class is shown below: I only exclude H2Console path.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepo) {
        return username -> {
            User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

            if(user != null) {
                return user;
            }
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User \"" + username + "\" not found");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Console())
                .and()
                .headers((headers) -> headers.frameOptions().sameOrigin())
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/design","/orders").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/design")
                                .permitAll()
                ).logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                                .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: is that a Maven project? If so, do you have <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId> in your pom?

Comment: @dsp_user, Thank you, but I tried to add it and for some reason maven cannot find the dependency

Comment: that's another problem, and you can post a separate question for that. Still, I think you need that dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@dsp_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119161/dsp-user).
Problem solved by adding `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` dependency